# Is meaning of rated voltage not always same?

Tags: connector, ratings

Well, I'm stuck in choosing DC barrel jack which will supply power for my circuit board from 12V 1.5A AC/DC adapter. Its spec says voltage rating is 18V and current rating is 1.5A. Well.. I know that for IC devices I should supply voltage near the voltage rating to guarantee their proper operations. How about these type of parts like connector, socket, etc... ? Can I just go on with this barrel jack with 12V 1.5A supply?

Comment: The voltage rating on a connector is a maximum. Using it at any lower voltage is fine.

Comment: @ThePhoton Then I'll go with my DC barrel jack. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you do not *exceed* the rated voltage or current, your application will be fine.